# JPA Primary Key in separate sequence tables

Tags: mysql, jpa, entity, eclipselink

I have multiple entities annotated with the following:

```
@TableGenerator(name = "XXX_Gen", table = "XXX_GEN", pkColumnName = "GEN_NAME", valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Id
private String id;
```

I am using MySQL behind the scenes with eclipselink and the problem is that regardless of the values that I enter in the `name` and `table` MySQL always just uses a single table called 'SEQUENCE' to increment the PK's values.

Normally this isn't an issue except I have a specific case where I need an entity to have its own incremental sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't specifying the generator! It should be;

```
@TableGenerator(name = "XXX_Gen", table = "XXX_GEN", pkColumnName = "GEN_NAME", valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator="XXX_Gen")
@Id
private String id;
```

I think I need another cup of coffee!